# What does ActionText Table correspond to in WiX 3.8

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I am asking the correspondence in WiX for ActionText table, refered in MSDN page [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Or rather, how can we provide hint text while system events are happening, like the installer is moving files or writing to registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the elements in WiX are documented in the help file with a list of Windows Installer references.  This enables you to search the help backwards to find out which element expresses said table.  In this case it's the ProgressText element.

This [link](http://web.mit.edu/ops/services/afs/openafs-1.4.1/src/src/WINNT/install/wix/lang/en_US/ActionText.wxi) might be useful to you if you want to add action text for the build in standard actions.