# VS2010 Setup Project - Adding Text to Progress bar dynamically

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I'm creating an msi package with few exe files using visual studio 2010. The progress bar shows a message "Please Wait.." when the installation is going on. I need to show separate texts "Copying files" "Installing xyz" etc for every custom action on the progress bar.

Could you please provide your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for doing this in VS setups. The messages originate from the ActionText table in the MSI file, and VS adds nothing to it. This SO post describes the WiX implementation and samples:

[What does ActionText Table correspond to in WiX 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675059/what-does-actiontext-table-correspond-to-in-wix-3-8)

but basically you'd need to populate that ActionText table in the MSI file with the right templates to get those things shown. If you have any MSI files built by other tools you might see some examples. You could try (with Orca) adding this your ActionTest table in one row:

Action is InstallFiles

Description is Copying new files

Template is     [1] ([6] B) to [9]

and see if you get some file copying messages.